# Web-based RSS/feed aggregator that sends email digest?

Tags: rss, feeds

Can you recommend a good RSS aggregator that sends regular email digest to me?

I would like to be able to add a few feeds and then, say every day or every week it will send an email containing my list of subscribed articles.

I found [Feed My Inbox](http://www.feedmyinbox.com/) but there you can do very limited things with a free account.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't personally used this, but you could use the following site: http://feed.informer.com/ or you could technically use Yahoo Pipes to aggregate the feeds together and use FeedBurner to send a daily digest.

Comment: how do I send a daily digest using FeedBurner? I played around and didn't find the option.

Comment: A bit of a hack, but add the feed via FeedBurner, go to the feed options page, and then click the 'publicize' tab. There should be an 'Email Subscriptions' link on the left-side - click that. Go to the link specified under 'Subscription Link Code' section and visit the link specified in the textbox. You should be able to subscribe yourself that way.

Answer (score 1):

**Check out [FriendFeed](http://friendfeed.com/)**

FriendFeed was designed to be used more as a real-time stream, but you can use it as a regular feed aggregator if you want. You can set it to give you email notifications -- in real time, best of day, or best of week -- or IMs in real-time.

Answer (score 1):

You can try using ifttt.com

You will need tell it to take an RSS feed and email it to you. Should only take a few minutes to setup.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try [Blogtrottr](https://blogtrottr.com/about/):

> As the name suggests, we deliver fresh and nutritious news to your
>   inbox. What makes us different? We send you the things you need, at
>   your convenience. Rather than having to constantly scour blogs and
>   websites, (and forget half the ones you follow) we mail you updates
>   from your own personal selection, on schedules that you choose.